# Page Template Selector Error

Tags: templates, plugin-polylang

Complement of the season.

Please, am currently having issues with my project (berrywell.de).

The English homepage automatically selects German homepage template after assigning it to the English template and saved, and vice versa. Thus, setting both German homepage and English homepage to the default last saved template (i.e either the German template or English template).

I have checked the source code, but couldn’t identify any error. I have also upgraded the WordPress version along with plugin but that doesn’t resolve the problem either.

I would appreciate any useful hint to resolve this, please.

Thank you

Br.
FT Ayeni

Comment: do you use a plugin for localisation ? or you have just 2 templates with names "english" and "deutsch" ?

Comment: I use Polylang plugin for the translation. Though I have two templates, one for English and the other for German.

Comment: polylang can synchronise template for all languages of a post. you can change that in polylang settings.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! It works now. :)